# How do you fit a linear mixed model with an AR(1) random effects correlation structure in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to rerun someone else's project, so we need to use some macros in R.

Here comes a very basic question:

`m1.nlme = lme(log.bp.dia ~ M25.9to9.ma5iqr + temp.c.9to9.ma4iqr + o3.ma5iqr + sea_spring + sea_summer + sea_fall + BMI + male + age_ini, data=barbara.1.clean, random = ~ 1|study_id)`

Since the model is using AR(1) [autocorrelation 1 covariance model] in SAS for within person variance, I am not sure how to do this in R.

And where I can see the index for different models, like unstructured?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by "index" for different models, but to specify an AR(1) covariance structure for the residuals, you can add `corr=corAR1()` to your lme call.

Comment: +1, I think they mean [?corClasses](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/nlme/html/corClasses.html). @user, you should check the documentation here: [?lme](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/nlme/html/lme.html).

Answer (score 0):

The correlation at lag $1$ is say $r$, where $-1< r <1$ for a stationary $AR(1)$ model.  The correlation at lag $k \geq 1$ is $r^k$. This gives you the autocovariance matrix by just multiplying by the variance of $X_t$.